# Product Import - Websites

Tags: product, import

Having a few issues with Product import

I have 3 websites each with 1 store eg:

UK:  Store:  Admin, Website: Base
DE:  Store: de, Website: de
IT:  Store: it, Website: it

I do my initial import:

```
store|websites|attribute_set|prodtype|
admin|base|Default|configurable|
```

and the product goes in fine

But then I try to import my language version:

```
store|websites|attribute_set|prodtype|
de|de|Default|configurable|
```

It goes in fine, but then removes the product from the initial Website!

How do I configure the CSV, so that it does not lose the Website/stores, but also knows which store it is importing the content into?

Comment: are you using the default import or some extension like Magmi?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on my import it was not recognising the root category for the product, therefore it was importing the content, but placing it in the UK category instead of the DE category.  I then needed to change the wabsite root folder in the import profile to reflect the website importing into.